# How do Harry and Hermione get back their wands in "Order of the Phoenix"?

Tags: harry-potter

They're caught in Umbridge's office and she confiscates their wands. Hermione leads them into the forest, Umbridge is carted off, and Hermione and Harry then leave the forest, still complaining about their missing wands. They meet up with friends, fly to London, and start using their wands. When did they get the wands back?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ron, Ginny, Neville and Luna brought them back to the forest

> 'Well, we can't do anything without wands,' said Hermione hopelessly,
>   dragging herself up  again. 'Anyway, Harry, how exactly were you
>   planning to get all the way to London?' 'Yeah, we were just wondering
>   that,' said a familiar voice from behind her. Harry and Hermione moved
>   together instinctively and peered through the trees. Ron came into
>   sight, closely followed by Ginny, Neville and Luna. All of them looked
>   a little  the worse for wear - there were several long scratches
>   running the length of Ginny's cheek; a  large purple lump was swelling
>   above Neville's right eye; Ron's lip was bleeding worse than  ever -
>   but all were looking rather pleased with themselves. **'So,' said Ron,
>   pushing aside a low-hanging branch and holding out Harry's wand, 'had
>   any  ideas?'** 'How did you get away?' asked Harry in amazement, taking
>   his wand from Ron. 'Couple of Stunners, a Disarming Charm, Neville
>   brought off a really nice little Impediment  Jinx,' said Ron airily,
>   now handing back Hermione's wand, too. 'But Ginny was best, she got 
>   Malfoy - Bat Bogey Hex - it was superb, his whole face was covered in
>   the great flapping  things. Anyway, we saw you out of the window
>   heading into the Forest and followed.